# How do I remove leading text from this string

Tags: awk, sed, aix

How do I remove all the chars up to the number 41 in this line
all the way to the number 41

```
##SHUTDOWN_MAINT##41 * * * * /vend/oracle/util/bin
```

Comment: Are you changing the file, or command output? What's your key pattern here? Removing `##SHUTDOWN_MAINT##` or removing everything till `41` or removing till any number?

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear to me whether or not you want the `41` included in your output. Accordingly here are two sets of options

**1. Removing text upto and including `41`**

If you are running `bash` you can use built-in variable processing

```
line='##SHUTDOWN_MAINT##41 * * * * /vend/oracle/util/bin'
printf "%s\n" "${line#*41}"
```

If you can guarantee that there is no other `41` on the line you could use `sed`

```
line='##SHUTDOWN_MAINT##41 * * * * /vend/oracle/util/bin'
printf "%s\n" "$line" | sed 's/^.*41//'
```

If you have GNU `grep` you can pick off everything following the `41`

```
line='##SHUTDOWN_MAINT##41 * * * * /vend/oracle/util/bin'
printf "%s\n" "$line" | grep -Po '(?<=41).*'
```

**2. Removing text upto but excluding `41`, using the `##` as a marker**

If you are running `bash` you can use built-in variable processing

```
line='##SHUTDOWN_MAINT##41 * * * * /vend/oracle/util/bin'
printf "%s\n" "${line#*?##}"
```

If you can guarantee that there is no other `##` on the line you could use `sed`

```
line='##SHUTDOWN_MAINT##41 * * * * /vend/oracle/util/bin'
printf "%s\n" "$line" | sed 's/^..*##//'
```

If you have GNU `grep` you can pick off everything following the `##`

```
line='##SHUTDOWN_MAINT##41 * * * * /vend/oracle/util/bin'
printf "%s\n" "$line" | grep -Po '(?<=.##).*'
```

Comment: How about `"${line##*##}"` -- from the beginning, remove the longest string that ends with 2 hashes.

Comment: That would work too. You'll see I've extended my question to cater for both possibilities (using `?##` as my glob match - although re-reading I do like your more precise `##*##`).

Answer (score 0):

You could use sed to remove everything until the first digit

`echo '##SHUTDOWN_MAINT##41 * * * * /vend/oracle/util/bin' | sed 's/[^0-9]*//'`

If you want change it in a file use

`sed -i 's/[^0-9]*//' filename`

Hope that helps

Cheers

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer I wish I could use -i but on AIX its not a switch. Thanks

Comment: @VirginiaWalters I've amended your question so it's clear you're using AIX

Comment: @VirginiaWalters `sed -i 's/[^0-9]*//' filename` can be rewritten without the `-i` flag like this `sed 's/[^0-9]*//' filename >filename.tmp && mv -f filename.tmp filename; rm -f filename.tmp`